# json_encode and JSON.parse does not harmonize

Tags: javascript, php, json

I get this output on my php page with json_encode

```
{"id":"761","user":"Moderator","message":"test"} 
{"id":"760","user":"Patrick","message":"test"}
```

Now i want to parse theses values with JSON.parse in javascript, to get an array.
But it does not work.

It works only if i have one json Objekt.

What is the best way to solve this?

To split at '}' and parse every string that i will get?

Comment: can you not json_encode all your results as one (e.g. an Array)?

Comment: Please show a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` of your PHP array, and the relevant PHP that generates the array and JSON - what you're outputting isn't a single JSON object, which is why `JSON.parse` fails

Comment: For every entry in my database i use echo json_encode($array).
But if i would put all entries in the array only the last one will print with json_encode.

This is my print_r($array)

Array
(
    [id] => 761
    [user] => Moderator
    [message] => test
)
Array
(
    [id] => 760
    [user] => Patrick
    [message] => test
)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}{}` is not valid JSON.  You need to have an array wrap these and separate them with commas like `[{},{}]`.  You can do this in PHP via:

```
$entries = array();
foreach ($database_entry as $array) {
    $entries[] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($entries);
```

That is you should only call `json_encode` *once*.

Comment: thanks....this solution works.
faster then the light. that means i get my solution before the problem occurs. :D

Answer (score 1):

This output is not a proper JSON object or array.  What you want to do is wrap your objects in square brackets, and separate them with commas.  The output should look like this:

```
[{"id":"761","user":"Moderator","message":"test"}, 
{"id":"760","user":"Patrick","message":"test"}]
```

You will need to change your PHP to generate the output in this way.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse applies only strings:

```
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
```

**text** is
the string to parse as JSON.  See the JSON object for a description of JSON syntax. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to output the objects into a JSON array, with each object/array item separated by a comma:

```
{ 
  "users": [
      {"id":"761","user":"Moderator","message":"test"}, 
      {"id":"760","user":"Patrick","message":"test"}
  ]
}
```